# Laravel 5.6 Auth Logout Fail

Tags: php, e-commerce, laravel

commerce with Laravel. I click the "Log Out" button, but the Exit Process does not work.

I'm not getting any errors. He's just leading me to the homepage.

web.php Code

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'kullanici'], function() {
Route::get('/logout', 'KullaniciController@logout')->name('kullanici.logout'); });
```

Controller Code

```
    use Illuminate\Auth;

   public function logout() {

    auth()->logout();
     return redirect('/');
}
```

Html Code

```
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('kullanici.logout') }}" >Çıkış Yap</a>
```

Comment: Logging out these days goes with a post request and not a get. Make a form, csrf token and post the form to the logout route

Answer (score 1):

**You should try this**

```
public function logout() {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
}
```